# Kotlin - How to decide between "lateinit" and "nullable variable"?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am confuse for lateinit and nullable variable, which one to use for variable.

```
lateinit var c: String
var d: String? = null
c = "UserDefinedTarget"

// if not added initialisation for c than throws UninitializedPropertyAccessException
if (c == "UserDefinedTarget") {
    //do some stuff.
}
//not throws any exception whether d is initialise or not.
if(d == "UserDefinedTarget") {
     //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: If you are absolutely sure a variable will be initialised BEFORE being used. You can use lateinit. Use nullable variables otherwise

Comment: for lateint add check if (this::c.isInitilized())

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A type that is nullable is just that, a thing that has a valid state that is null.

A non-nullable late init var represents something where null is an invalid state, but for some reason you can't populate it in the constructor.

Android Activities are a good example of a use of lateinit. Activities must have a no args constructor and their lifecycle only really starts with onCreate().

Comment: `lateinit` can be null?

Comment: `lateinit` is only for avoid null checks in future, that's why `lateinit` modifier is not allowed on properties of nullable types.

Answer (score 28):

> These are two **completely different** concepts.

You can use `lateinit` to avoid *null checks* when referencing the property. It's very convenient in case your properties are initialized through dependency injection, or, for example, in the setup method of a unit test.

However, you should keep in mind that accessing a `lateinit` property before it has been initialized throws an exception.  That means you should use them only if you are absolutely sure, they **will** be initialized.

*Nullable types*, on the other hand, are used when a variable **can hold** `null`.

---

```
class A {
    lateinit var a: String

    fun cat() {
        print(a.length)  // UninitializedPropertyAccessException is thrown
        a = "cat"
        print(a.length)  // >>> 3
    }
}

class B {
    var b: String? = null

    fun dog() {
        print(b.length)  // won't compile, null check is obligatory here
        print(b?.length) // >>> null
        b = "dog"
        print(b?.length) // >>> 3
    }
}
```

---

*For more information:*

- [Late-initialized properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties)
- [Nullable types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types)

Answer (score 13):

It depends.
Nullable variable means that variable can hold value or null. `lateinit` means that variable **must** be initialised later. It should be initialized before accessing it. If you attempt accessing uninitialized `lateinit` variable `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` will be thrown.

It's always better to avoid using nulls in your app. Nulls are evil. So if you can initialize variable in `onCreate` then it's better to use `lateinit`. Also if you use dependency injection in your app and fields should be injected it's also a valid case to use `lateinit` instead of handling nulls.

If for some reason you can't initialize variable, initializing code can result to null, or null can be assigned to this variable later than you should use nullable variable. Generally speaking if null is a valid value for the variable.

Answer (score 4):

Use `lateinit` for properties that cannot be initialized in a constructor.

Comment: Don't you mean usse `lateinit` for properties that can be initialized in the constructor. If you use lateinit and don't initialize it a constructor then you run the risk of accessing it before its been initialized resulting in a exception.

Comment: @ant2009 If you were to initialize it in the constructor, then the property is - by definition - not `lateinit`. Should you initialize a `lateinit` property in the constructor, the Kotlin compiler emits a `UNNECESSARY_LATEINIT` warning.

Comment: @TheKvist Thanks for pointing that out. if the lateinit property is initialized in a constructor its always guarenteed to be iniitialized as the constructor will always run. However, if you have a lateinit property and its not initialized in the constructor but in another method you can always check if its been initialized or not by using this `if(::fullName.isInitialized()) { /* do something */ }` This is what I normally do.

Comment: @ant2009 To use the `isInitialized` is how you should do it :) Just realized your original comment is over a year old, so sorry for necroing, and thanks for replying!

The thing is, if you can guarantee that you will initialize the property in the constructor, there is no reason for the property to be marked as `lateinit` as it will never be "initialized later", hence the compiler warning.

Personally, in classes where I have lateinit props, I define a simple `validate` method that checks itself for the lateinits to be initialized and throws an exception if they're not.

Comment: @TheKvist how does that differ from a null check? Just seems like a slower version without language integrated operators.

Comment: @Benjamin The main difference is that you can not "uninitialize" a lateinit var once initialized, whereas you can set a nullable to null. Null in a nullable is - of course - not a value to express "invalid", but rather a value to express "nothing", and that might change at any given time. "Uninitialized" in lateinit just means "invalid", which null can't express. A "variable that might change from 'something' to 'nothing' at any given time" is both conceptually and semantically different from a "variable that is initialized at some later time and is guaranteed to stay initialized after that"

Comment: @Benjamin Sorry for the follow up, but regarding the "slower version" part of your comment: It definitely looks like it's slower, but only when you treat a lateinit how you would treat a nullable.
When used correctly, you'll only have to check a lateinit exactly *once* and if that check succeeds, you can then pretend as if it never was a lateinit to begin with.
With a nullable, you'll have to check for null *every time*, because it might have been set to null by some other code.

Comment: @TheKvist I'm still not really seeing the difference? You could treat a nullable variable the same "correct" way you should be treating lateinit vars and get the same result. There is no magic that makes execution skip over the isInitialized check if it's already been done, it's (as far as I can tell) all syntactic sugar over the implicitly nullable IL. 

If you're arguing that you are giving information to a reader (including tools) about the *intent* of the variable, that's fine. But if your read access to the variable is guarded, there is no meaningful performance benefit.

Comment: @Benjamin `lateinit` specifically exists to avoid guarding every read access when your program flow can guarantee that the property is checked at some time before any read access occurs. There is no way for the property to get unset in the time between your one single check and all the reads after. With a nullable, the compiler will force you to check your property every time before a read, because some code _could_ have set it to null some time before.
Performance-wise, there is of course no real difference here (the check itself is as you said the same), but less checks are less checks.

Comment: I think my point is that the compiler doesn't garuntee the value is ever initialized, so in practice you still have to check whether the value has been initialized, because in my experience devs are not great about actually garunteeing that all code paths initialize the value. It's great when something systemic like dagger is supposed to be garunteeing initialization. In basically every other case I've seen it puts the burden on the user of the class to garuntee initialization (i.e. forcing the user to call an init method).