# android - How to set a Fragment on Activity OnCreate? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Im currently working on an app which has a Settings Activity. In this activity, there is a FrameLayout, that loads the Settings Main fragment.

When i try to load the fragment in onCreate of the activity using a function that contains the supportFragmentManager i get the error `Unable to start activity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to a context`. The weird thing is, Android Studio, points at `val frgSettingsMain = FragmentSettingsMain()` and `DataItemsSettings`.

**What am i doing wrong? Are there any other cleaner ways to initialize a Fragment in onCreate?**

**Code:**

**ActivitySettings.kt**

```
class ActivitySettings : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        topToolbarBack.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }

        val frgSettingsMain = FragmentSettingsMain()

        setCurrentFragment(frgSettingsMain)

    }

    private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.framelayoutSettings, fragment)
            commit()
        }
}
```

**FragmentSettingsMain.kt**

```
class FragmentSettingsMain : Fragment(), AdapterSettings.OnItemClickListener {
    val settingsList = listOf(
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.look), getString(R.string.lookdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_color_lens),
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.playing), getString(R.string.playingdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_view_carousel),
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.images), getString(R.string.imagesdscription), R.drawable.ic_colored_image),
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.audio), getString(R.string.audiodescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_volume_up),
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.other), getString(R.string.otherdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_shape),
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.about), getString(R.string.aboutdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_info)
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings_main, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        rvSettings.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = AdapterSettings(settingsList, this@FragmentSettingsMain)
        }
    }

    override fun OnItemClick(position: Int) {
        when(position) {
            0 -> Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed Option 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            1 -> Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed Option 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            2 -> Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed Option 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            3 -> Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed Option 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            4 -> Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed Option 4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            5 -> Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed Option 5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that method `getstring()` needs context. The context is not attached to the Fragment when you call FragmentSettingsMain(). Try to initialize variable settingsList after the Fragment is added to the container. For example:

```
lateinit var settingsList : List<DataItemSettings>
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true
        settingsList = listOf(
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.look), getString(R.string.lookdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_color_lens),
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.playing), getString(R.string.playingdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_view_carousel),
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.images), getString(R.string.imagesdscription), R.drawable.ic_colored_image),
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.audio), getString(R.string.audiodescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_volume_up),
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.other), getString(R.string.otherdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_shape),
        DataItemsSettings(getString(R.string.about), getString(R.string.aboutdescription), R.drawable.ic_colored_info)
    )

    }
```

Comment: Perfect! It is for vars that cannot be initialized in the constructor (follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796102/kotlin-how-to-decide-between-lateinit-and-nullable-variable/44796976)link for some lateinit var usages). For example you can check whether the var is initialized or not `this::settingsList.isInitialized`, which can be useful.