# Declare ImageView in kotlin Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview

What I want is to do this (which is in Java):

```
public class MainActivity exteds AppCompatActivity{
    ImageView logo;

    @override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
    }
```

when taking it to Kotlin I get an error:

[image]

Please could you tell me which of the options to keep so that the error does not appear?

[image]

and what class is `TODO()`?

Comment: I already tried to change val to var

Comment: People here will like it more, of you add the error message and code, rather than links to images.

Comment: Also, your Java code isn't valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lateinit` which will allow you to initialize the property later on.

```
lateinit var logo: ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    logo = findViewById(R.id.logo)
}
```

Comment: What language is this?  It's not Java or Kotlin

Comment: updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize as `null` and later use it

```
var logo: ImageView? = null
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_layout)
        logo = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
    }
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, short and simple

Answer (score 1):

You can't reassign a val, so I would suggest you make it a var. Since you also want to initialize it later, you will need to declare a lateinit var, i.e `lateinit var logo: ImageView` or you can initialize it as null i.e `var logo: ImageView? = null` and then later you can reassign as initented `logo = findViewById(R.id.logo)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this `logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);` in kotlin then you don't need to declare any extra variable you can simply use `logo.setOnClickListener {  }` or anything similar kotlin will directly import it from your xml.(Note :- here `logo` is your imageView id).

All though if you want to declare any variable and initialize it later on then you can use `lateinit var logo: ImageView` or simply and nullable variable like `var logo: ImageView? = null` and initialize it later on.
There are a lot of blogs and S.O Questions on google where you can find more about `lateinit` and `nullable` variables. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796102/kotlin-how-to-decide-between-lateinit-and-nullable-variable#:%7E:text=Nullable%20variable%20means%20that%20variable,be%20initialized%20before%20accessing%20it.&text=Use%20lateinit%20for%20properties%20that%20cannot%20be%20initialized%20in%20a%20constructor.) is one of the S.O question you can refer.