# how to set custom return type nullable in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, null, nullable, custom-data-type

I made a personal data type "email"
how can I make this type nullable in value.

For example.

```
private lateinit var a: email?
```

or

```
fun makeEmailAddress(a: String): email? {
   // TODO
}
```

Comment: Hi! A lateinit variable cannot be nullable, so you would have to remove lateinit https://stackoverflow.com/a/44796205/13679469

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lateinit var` uses nulls behind the scenes to represent the uninitialized value, so they cannot be of nullable types from the point of view of the program. That said, this limitation is in general not a problem because most of the time the point of using `lateinit var` is so that you can use non-null types while still delaying initialization.

If you need a nullable property, you can simply drop the `lateinit` modifier and initialize it to `null` when declaring it:

```kotlin
private var a: Email? = null
```

For the function declaration, the return type `Email?` should just work:

```
fun makeEmailAddress(a: String): Email? {
   // return whatever you need here, either null or an Email instance
}
```

Note that types are capitalized in Kotlin by convention, so I suggest you rename `email` to `Email` (I used the capitalized version in the sample code above).

Comment: Return type is 'Email?', which is not a subtype of overridden

Comment: I got this error, that is why I'm asking a question.

Comment: @Kyu-HoHwang then you're probably not sharing the actual code. You would only get this error if you're trying to override a method returning a non-nullable type with one that returns a nullable type. In that case you should make the parent method (from the interface or parent class) also return the nullable type to fix your problem. If that is not possible because callers cannot handle null, you need to re-think the logic of your code so that `makeEmailAddress` doesn't return null here (maybe some validation should occur up front or something)

Comment: data class Email(
    @get:PropertyName("results")
    val results: List<EmailDTO>,
)

Comment: this is the code what I'm use. I use firebase that I add this annotation. Is this the reason? And How can I change for solving this problem.

Comment: I meant the part with `makeEmailAddress`. Most likely that `makeEmailAddress` method exists in a parent class/interface, and you're trying to override it, right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solve this problem.